# Using ASP.NET Identity 2.2.1 with my own table in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I installed identity 2.2.1 today.  I created my own classes for Role, User, Claim, UserManager, UserRole, EmailService and SmsService.  The above classes seem to be working.

I added a new class called SignInManager. I can't seem to fix the error message. I'm getting a convert error message.

```
public class MySignInManager : SignInManager<MyUser, long>
{
    public MySignInManager(MyUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
    {
    }
```

**Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'**

```
    public override Task<MyClaim> CreateUserIdentityAsync(MyUser user)
    {
        return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((MyUserManager)UserManager);
    }
```

This method is okay

```
    public static MySignInManager      Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<MySignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new MySignInManager(context.GetUserManager<MyUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
    }
```

The user Class looks like this:

```
 public class MyUser : IdentityUser<long, MyLogin, MyUserRole, MyClaim>
 {
     public string ActivationToken { get; set; }

     public string PasswordAnswer { get; set; }

     public string PasswordQuestion { get; set; }

     public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(MyUserManager userManager)
     {
         var userIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
         // Add custom user claims here
         return userIdentity;
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The method ends in `Async`, which is always a good indication that you need to use async semantics:

```
public async override Task<MyClaim> CreateUserIdentityAsync(MyUser user)
{
    return await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((MyUserManager)UserManager);
}
```

i.e. add `async` to the method signature and `await` the result

Comment: Thanks for the response : Now I am getting this error message RobExample.MySignInManager.CreateUserIdentityAsync(RobExample.MyUser)': return type must be 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity>' to match overridden member 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInManager<RobExample.MyUser,long>.CreateUserIdentityAsync(RobExample.MyUser)'

Comment: I've only got 2.0 but `SignInManager<TUser, TKey>` clearly has the method as `public virtual Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(TUser user)`. I have a suspicion you should be overriding `UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync` and not `SignInManager`? I'm no Identity Guru, however.

Comment: Forgot to respond back to you. Thanks.  It's working now.

Comment: @RThompson Glad to hear it. Possibly you could post your own an answer to your question to explain how you solved things - it will help others in future.

Answer (score 0):

I changed Task MyClaim to Task ClaimsIdentity to fix the problem.

```
    public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(PoseyUser user)
    {
        return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((PoseyUserManager)UserManager);
    }
```